# VBA- Match headers with multiple rows using a mapping table

Tags: vba, dictionary, merge, header, mapping

I have a workbook with *Sheet1*, *Sheet2*, *Mapping*. I want to copy values from *Sheet1* to *Sheet2* based on both row/column headers in both sheets. The column headers are not the same, so I've created a mapping table in "Mapping" Sheet to match those headers.

- The problem is that those headers are made from multiple rows- see this: [image]

For example I need that **(POS1 2019 Emp1) = (HR Department Employee 1)**.
The following code it's working but only if the mapping table looks like this:

[image]
(and also I've not added rows headers, I'm not sure how).

- So please do you have any idea how can I make the mapping with multiple headers work? Should I put those headers in two separate named ranges? Any advice will be appreciated :)

Sheet1:
[image]

Sheet2:
[image]

Result that I want:
[image]

```
Public Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    stack "Sheet2", "Sheet1", "Mapping"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
    
Public Sub stack(ByVal Sheet1 As String, ByVal Sheet2 As String, ByVal Mapping As String)
    Dim rng As Range, trgtCell As Range, src As Worksheet, trgt As Worksheet, helper As Worksheet
                
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
                
    Set src = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set trgt = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set helper = Worksheets("Mapping")
            
    With src
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Rows(3), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            Dim lkup As Variant
            With helper
                lkup = Application.VLookup(rng.Value, .Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), 2, False)
            End With
            If Not IsError(lkup) Then
                        
                Set trgtCell = trgt.Range("$B$2:$F$6").Find(lkup, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                                           
                If Not trgtCell Is Nothing Then
                    .Range(rng.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
                    With trgt
                        .Range(Split(trgtCell.Address, "$")(1) & 3).PasteSpecial
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```